# Business rule to populate a picklist field only when opportunity stage is closed won

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I have to implement a business rule where a picklist field needs to be populated only when the opportunity stage is closed won.Also for a particular record type only

How can I achieve this with point and click in salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Read up about validation rules, maybe a trailhead course?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules

Something like

```
ISPICKVAL(MyField__c, '') && !(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won') && RecordType.DeveloperName = 'XYZ')
```